# How to create and use global static class/singleton in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, singleton

I need some class or singleton object globally-accessible in controllers and easy to use. Now it is implemented in the `libs/` folder like this:

```
class User
  class << self

    @user = nil
    attr_reader :uid, :name

    def init session
      if session[:user_info].nil?
        @user = nil
      end

      @user = session_data[:user]
    end

    def signed_in?
      @user.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def guest?
      not signed_in?
    end

  end
end
```

This code obviously is not good, as User initialized only once on application start, and in case of improper use User wouldn't be updated. I want to save ability to use the class or object without much addition steps, but have a new global instance for every new connection. How it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a standard "current user" method. I think you're complicating things a bit. All you need to do is load a user object based on session information and cache it in an instance variable. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

The first time you call it, it will look up the current user based on the ID stored in the session. Subsequent calls will return the user object you already loaded. If the user is not signed in, `current_user` will simply be `nil`.

Comment: Oh, this could work with the new User instance creation, thank you! I think `current_user` isn't standard, but added by the Devise gem. And I can't use it as my workflow is much different unfortunatly.

Comment: By standard, I just meant commonly used. Devise uses the same approach because it was already very common in custom auth systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `include Singleton` to your User class definition and then use `User.instance` go get the user instance.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in **Application Controller** as this is the base class of all the classes. Doing so it will be globally-accessible in all the controllers as well.